# Wordpress; Weptile Slider overlaying menus

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

I'm working on a Worpress site and I stumbled upon this annoying problem: On the very top of my index page I got a widget area which is displaying a Weptile Slider. Everything is a ok except slider is overlaying a Worpress menu (in header.php). What I'm trying to do is to push the slider into background, so the menus will dropdown correctly on top of the slider content. Right now the nav bar is useless. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jsfiddle and etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use z-index:999; css for menu container.